# AMO - Dynamically dropping partition based on SQL lookup using foreach loop

Tags: c#, ssis, ssas

I am attempting to build an SSIS script task that will check the name of a partition on an SSAS cube against a list of partitions in a database view. If the partition exists but is not in the list, it is dropped, otherwise it is processed.

The script appears to work in so far as the partition *will* be dropped, however it appears unable to continue the loop and generates an enum error with the drop as follows:

[image: Enum error whilst dropping partition]

Running the script only attempting to process instead (i.e. `rowCount == 1` and `pt.Process()` with no `else` condition) works fine and completes with no errors.  It appears that I cannot delete the partition whilst looping through it's collection.  I would be grateful on pointers how to drop these partitions if they are found in the SQL lookup table.

```
   public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            String Server = Dts.Variables["User::Connection"].Value.ToString();
            String Cube = "CubeName";
            String conn = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + Server + ";";


            Server MDXServer = new Server();
            MDXServer.Connect(conn);

            foreach (Database db in MDXServer.Databases)
            {
                foreach (Cube cb in db.Cubes)
                {
                    if (cb.Name == Cube)
                    {
                        foreach (MeasureGroup mg in cb.MeasureGroups)
                        {
                            foreach (Partition pt in mg.Partitions)
                            {
                                string PartName = (pt.Name.ToString());

                                //Create SQL query to reference the parition view and check row count when partition name used in predicate:
                                string sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dim].[Partitions] WHERE [FinWeek] = @pt;";
                                // Open DB connection:
                                ConnectionManager cm;
                                cm = Dts.Connections["FIP_Server_Alias"];
                                SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
                                // Link the query and the connection string together as a command
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection);
                                // Add a value to the parameter in the SQL query
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt", PartName);


                                // Activate reader to read the resulting data set from the query
                                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                while (reader.Read()) //while loop performs an action whilst the reader is open
                                {
                                    // Put the second result of query (0 woudl be first) into a string variable in the script task
                                    string rowCount = reader[0].ToString();

                                    //if the partition exists but is not in the database dim.Partitions view, drop from collection.
                                    if (rowCount == "0")
                                    {
                                        pt.Drop();
                                    }
                                }
                                //End the read loop
                                reader.Close();

                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }



        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.ToString());
        }


        Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the solution I found with Tab Alleman's steer to add it to a collection.  The partition list is looped through in a second `foreach` loop after I have finish querying the server itself.  I create a new `XmlaWarningCollection` and drop from there, which seems to maintain the connection.  It drops all partitions not listed in my database view.

Further help can be found on this Microsoft blog:
https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/rafats/2009/02/10/how-to-partition-cube-using-c/

```
    public void Main()
    {
        try
        {
            String Server = Dts.Variables["User::Connection"].Value.ToString();
            String Cube = "TestCube";
            String conn = "Provider=MSOLAP;Data Source=" + Server + ";";


            Server MDXServer = new Server();
            MDXServer.Connect(conn);

            //Add collection to contain partitions to be dropped
            List<Partition> partitions = new List<Partition>();

            foreach (Database db in MDXServer.Databases)
            {
                foreach (Cube cb in db.Cubes)
                {
                    if (cb.Name == Cube)
                    {
                        foreach (MeasureGroup mg in cb.MeasureGroups)
                        {
                            foreach (Partition pt in mg.Partitions)
                            {
                                string PartName = (pt.Name.ToString());

                                //Create SQL query to reference the parition view and check row count when partition name used in predicate:
                                string sqlString = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM [dim].[Partitions] WHERE [Partition] = @pt;";
                                // Open DB connection:
                                ConnectionManager cm;
                                cm = Dts.Connections["Server_Alias"];
                                SqlConnection connection = (SqlConnection)cm.AcquireConnection(Dts.Transaction);
                                // Link the query and the connection string together as a command
                                SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sqlString, connection);
                                // Add a value to the parameter in the SQL query
                                cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pt", PartName);

                                // Activate reader to read the resulting data set from the query
                                SqlDataReader reader = cmd.ExecuteReader();

                                while (reader.Read()) //while loop performs an action whilst the reader is open
                                {
                                    // Put the result of query into a string variable in the script task
                                    string rowCount = reader[0].ToString();

                                    //if the partition exists but is not in the database dim.Partitions view, drop from collection.
                                    if (rowCount == "0")
                                    {
                                        partitions.Add(pt);
                                    }
                                }
                                //End the read loop
                                reader.Close();
                                }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            //Loop through the collection created in the above foreach loop and drop the partitions in it from the server.
            foreach (Partition dropPartition in partitions)
            {
                XmlaWarningCollection warningColln = new XmlaWarningCollection();
                dropPartition.Drop(DropOptions.Default, warningColln);
            }
         Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Success;
        }



          catch (Exception ex)
        {
            //catch error and return error to package for logging 
            Dts.Events.FireError(0, "Script task error: ", ex.Message + "\r" + ex.StackTrace, String.Empty, 0);
            Dts.TaskResult = (int)ScriptResults.Failure;  
        }



    }
```

Answer (score 1):

It's telling you that you can't modify the collection that you are looping through while you are looping through it.

So one way around this is not to drop the partition while you are in the `foreach` loop.   Instead add it to an array or string builder or other newly-created collection of your choice.

Then after the `foreach` loop, loop through your newly created collection, and drop the partition associated with each member of the collection.

Comment: Thanks for the response. The problem I have now is that the collection is not connected to a server object, see amended code in original question.

Comment: Well exactly, you need to loop through the `partitions` collection, and for each member you need to connect to the cube/measure group, create a "connected" reference to that specific partition and then drop it.

Comment: I've edited my code again to attempt to do that and get a server connection error.  Would you mind having  a look at my syntax and pointing out where I'm going wrong?  Thanks again.

Comment: You need to forget about looping when you want to drop the partition.   Yes, you loop through the disconnected collection.   But then you need to use some kind of "FindPartitionByName()" type of function (I'm not familiar with what functions are available, so I'm guessing) to grab a reference to the connected partition you want to drop.

Comment: Thanks for the steer,  I have worked out the answer now.